# No boot option after installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7, 64-bit

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit to run along with Windows 7 32-bit. It says the installation was successful, however when I restart the computer I do not get an option to select Ubuntu -- the computer automatically runs windows.

I'm running an Asus M5A97 for the motherboard. Here are the BIOS specs: 64Mb Flash ROM, UEFI BIOS, PnP, DMI 2.0, WfM 2.0, SM BIOS 2.7. System has 16GB RAM, with an AMD Processor.

Answer (score 0):

There may one of two problems:

- You incorrectly partitioned your hard drive
- You need to modify your BIOS to allow you to choose your boot-up OS

If you are absolutely certain that you have partitioned your hard drive correctly, try fiddling around with your BIOS settings. Every BIOS access key and menu is slightly different from one another but the concept is typically the same. Search for a menu that gives you an option to decide what to do at start up and select the option "OS to boot" and select the option related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, So I am pretty sure the partition was done correctly as i did it through the installation window for ubuntu. As for the BIOS Settings. I looked around in there and can't find any kind of OS to boot option. It only shows the HDD and the DVD Rom as my bootable options.

Comment: Try partitioning from the actual windows OS, for some reason, whenever you try to partition your hard drive through ubuntu and your preloaded OS is Windows 8, it doesn't typically partition correctly.

Comment: OK, so I have repartitioned the Drive, and have tried installing Ubuntu to the new partition I've Created. However the Partition Manager on the Installer keeps saying No Root when I try to install it to the partition i've created.

Comment: Did you format the partition? Or did you leave it completely blank? if you formattted the partition you then you will not be able to install ubuntu on it because it is formatted for windows rather than being a blank slate.

Comment: I did format it, I will retry without formatting it. Hopefully that fixes it.

Comment: Ok, have reinstalled Ubuntu with the unformatted partition. Installation worked like a champ, however still having the initial issue of only booting to windows. Thinking it's something in the bios but don't see any obvious settings....

Comment: Well that's great news to hear. However, it should just ask you which OS you want to load at the time of booting. Try doing it this way and see if you have any more luck than before. [Dual-Boot](http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm)

Comment: Well that worked... Kind of. I'm now being greeted with the bootloader option to boot ubuntu or windows 7. However when i boot to Ubuntu i'm greeted with grub4dos rather than ubuntu. How do I boot ubuntu from that. I've done some research and haven't really figured out how to.

Comment: It should theoretically just boot linux up automatically without having to do any further steps if you installed ubuntu correctly.

Comment: So Basically I Need to reinstall ubuntu...